# Поворот при помощи Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform

Есть два объекта, один который мы поворачиваем при помощи Rigidbody и второй, чей угол поворота он должен повторить.
Нужна помощь со скриптом, тот скрипт что я написал на данный момент, при некоторых положениях приводит к глюкам.

Вот часть кода:

```
    private Vector3 SpeedFindAng()
    {
        Vector3 tragetRot;
        Vector3 bodyRot;

        Quaternion Quat = Traget.transform.rotation;
        Vector3 XYZ = Vector3.zero;

        //Получение угла

        XYZ.x = Mathf.Atan2(2 * (Quat.w * Quat.x + Quat.y * Quat.z), 1 - 2 * (Quat.x * Quat.x + Quat.y * Quat.y));
        if (2 * (Quat.w * Quat.y - Quat.z * Quat.x) >= 1)
        {
            if (2 * (Quat.w * Quat.y - Quat.z * Quat.x) < 0)
            {
                XYZ.y = -Mathf.PI;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            XYZ.y = Mathf.Asin(2 * (Quat.w * Quat.y - Quat.z * Quat.x));
        }
        XYZ.z = Mathf.Atan2(2 * (Quat.w * Quat.z + Quat.x * Quat.y), 1 - 2 * (Quat.y * Quat.y + Quat.z * Quat.z));

        if (XYZ.x < 0)
        {
            XYZ.x = 360 * Mathf.Deg2Rad + XYZ.x;
        }

        if (XYZ.z < 0)
        {
            XYZ.z = 360 * Mathf.Deg2Rad + XYZ.z;
        }

        XYZ.y = Traget.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        tragetRot = XYZ / Mathf.Deg2Rad;


        Quat = Body.transform.rotation;

        XYZ.x = Mathf.Atan2(2 * (Quat.w * Quat.x + Quat.y * Quat.z), 1 - 2 * (Quat.x * Quat.x + Quat.y * Quat.y));
        if (2 * (Quat.w * Quat.y - Quat.z * Quat.x) >= 1)
        {
            if (2 * (Quat.w * Quat.y - Quat.z * Quat.x) < 0)
            {
                XYZ.y = -Mathf.PI;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            XYZ.y = Mathf.Asin(2 * (Quat.w * Quat.y - Quat.z * Quat.x));
        }
        XYZ.z = Mathf.Atan2(2 * (Quat.w * Quat.z + Quat.x * Quat.y), 1 - 2 * (Quat.y * Quat.y + Quat.z * Quat.z));

        if (XYZ.x < 0)
        {
            XYZ.x = 360 * Mathf.Deg2Rad + XYZ.x;
        }

        if (XYZ.z < 0)
        {
            XYZ.z = 360 * Mathf.Deg2Rad + XYZ.z;
        }

        XYZ.y = Body.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        bodyRot = XYZ / Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        //Нахождение разницы

        if (tragetRot.z - bodyRot.z < -180)
        {
            DeltaAng.z = 720 + (tragetRot.z - bodyRot.z);
        }
        else if (tragetRot.z - bodyRot.z > 180)
        {
            DeltaAng.z = (tragetRot.z - bodyRot.z) - 360;
        }

        if (tragetRot.y - bodyRot.y < -180)
        {
            DeltaAng.y = 720 + (tragetRot.y - bodyRot.y);
        }
        else if (tragetRot.y - bodyRot.y > 180)
        {
            DeltaAng.y = (tragetRot.y - bodyRot.y) - 360;
        }
        else
        {
            DeltaAng.y = tragetRot.y - bodyRot.y;
        }

        if (tragetRot.x - bodyRot.x < -180)
        {
            DeltaAng.x = 720 + (tragetRot.x - bodyRot.x);
        }
        else if (tragetRot.x - bodyRot.x > 180)
        {
            DeltaAng.x = (tragetRot.x - bodyRot.x) - 360;
        }
        else
        {
            DeltaAng.x = (tragetRot.x - bodyRot.x);
        }

        DeltaAng.x *= ModRot.x;
        DeltaAng.y *= ModRot.y;
        DeltaAng.z *= ModRot.z;

        print(bodyRot + " "+ tragetRot);
        print("U" + Quat.eulerAngles);

        DeltaAng = (Mathf.Deg2Rad * DeltaAng);
        SpeedRotXYZ = (DeltaAng / (Time.deltaTime * A)) * 0.02f;

        return SpeedRotXYZ;
    }
```

В этом коде объект(body) используя rigidbody повторяет угол поворота объекта(target).

Я вспомнил что написано в этом коде.
Когда я проверял прошлые версии этого кода, где еще использовались только углы эйлера, я заметил, что при вращении по оси X там нет 180°, по этому я использовал формулы преобразования кватернионов в углы эйлера.

Comment: Покажите, что Вы уже написали, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Vector3 SpeedFindAng()
{
    Quaternion targetRot = Target.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion bodyRot = Body.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion DeltaAngQ = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);

    //Нахождение разницы
    DeltaAngQ = targetRot * Quaternion.Inverse(bodyRot);

    if (DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.x > 180)
    {
        DeltaAng.x = DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.x - 360;
    }
    else
    {
        DeltaAng.x = DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.x;
    }

    if (DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.y > 180)
    {
        DeltaAng.y = DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.y - 360;
    }
    else
    {
        DeltaAng.y = DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.y;
    }

    if (DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.z > 180)
    {
        DeltaAng.z = DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.z - 360;
    }
    else
    {
        DeltaAng.z = DeltaAngQ.eulerAngles.z;
    }

    SpeedRotXYZ = DeltaAng;

    return SpeedRotXYZ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

отвечу не кодом.

у нас есть 2 квантериона. Мы их сравниваем что бы понять в какую сторону нужно поворачивать. Фактически сравниваем по каждой оси.

Как следствие у нас выйдет 4 переменных как результат сравнения.

Дальше мы по этих осях вычисляем будущее ускорение для поворота. Суть в том что чем больше разница - тем быстрее поворачиваем. НО! Нам нужно еще учесть что у нас должен быть порог при котором обьекты не будут задавать скорость(будут задавать нулевую скорость). Это нужно что бы избежать дерганья.

Ну и последний шаг -- задавание скорости при помощиRigidbody.MoveRotation.

---

Как альтернативное решение - можно задавать физический поворот одновременно двум обьектам.

Условно, если у тебя есть уже расчитанная скорость поворота одного из обьектов - применяй ее сразу на твоих 2 обьекта.

Это более оптимальное и простое решение, но оно может быть не всегда доступно.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так сделать.

Comment: А не знаете вариант без MoveRotation?

Comment: Rigidbody.angularVelocity

Comment: А также как сравнить 2 кватериона?

Comment: каждую ось отдельно сравниваем. Выходит 4 сравнения.

Comment: angularVelocity требует vector3, а дельта кватерниона при переводе в углы Эйлера выглядит странно, это точно сработает?
Или я, что то не то делаю?

Comment: ну тогда используй первые 3 вектора. Вообще я тебе чисто по памяти отвечаю, сейчас у меня даже не стоит юнити.

Comment: Я узнал как получить дельту кватернионов, нужно кватернион конечной позиции умножить на инвертированный кватернион начальной, после чего, дельту кватернионов можно переводить в углы Эйлера и начинать учет отрицательного поворота, а после это уже можно применить и в angularVelocity.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал использовать Quaternion.ToEulerAngles() или Quaternion.ToEuler() или новый вариант transform.rotation.eulerAngles.

И просто проверять в своих переменных Vector3 нужный поворот, вычитать или добавлять нужные значения и преобразовать обратно.

Comment: это не физический поворот. автора вопроса интересует физический

Answer (score 0):

Всё намного проще:

```
public class Foo: MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private float _rotationSpeed = 90;
    private Transform _transform;
    private IEnumerator _rotationCoroutine;

    private void Awake () {
        _transform = transform;
    }

    public void RotateTo (Vector3 target) {
        // станавливаем корутину, если есть
        if (_rotationCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(_rotationCoroutine);
        // запускаем новую корутину
        _rotationCoroutine = RotationCoroutine(target);
        StartCoroutine(_rotationCoroutine);
    }

    private IEnumerator RotationCoroutine (Vector3 target) {
        Vector3 baseRotation = _transform.eulerAngles;
        // угол между нунешнем и целевым
        float Angle = Vector3.Angle(baseRotation, target);
        // время поворота
        float RotationTime = Angle/_rotationSpeed;
        float Timer = 0;
        while (Timer < RotationTime) {
            float Way = Timer/RotationTime;
            _transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(baseRotation, target, Way);
            yield return null;
            Timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        _transform.localEulerAngles = target;
        _rotationCoroutine = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить что тут написано, а то я не все из этого могу понять.

Comment: Добавил комментариев.